# How can I hide a div till my page is completely loaded(when loading spinner goes hidden)

Tags: jquery

Am trying to hide a div during the page load while spinner is being shown while loading. But it doesn't work.

Here is what am trying to do:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(setTimeout(function() {
        //$('#results').hide();
        $("#spinner").fadeOut();
       //$('#results').show();
    }, 3000));
</script>
```

What am i missing?

How can I hide my div (id=results) while loading the page and I wanted to show it back once the page is completely loaded. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$( window ).load(function() {
  $('.show').show()
});
```

```css
.show{
display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show">
 HI  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code (if you uncomment the #results stuff) waits 3 seconds, hides `#result`, fades the spinner out, then shows `#result`.

You probably want to be hiding the result *before* waiting three seconds:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#results').hide();
    $(window).load(setTimeout(function() {
        $("#spinner").fadeOut();
        $('#results').show();
    }, 3000));
</script>
```

Of course, waiting 3 seconds isn't the ideal way to display a spinner, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader, as that's not directly related to the question.

You will also have improved results if you hide `#results` by default, possibly inline. Otherwise, you're likely to have lag on a slow network and/or slow device, resulting in `#result` being shown, then the javascript/CSS loading and hiding it, then showing it again after your spinner is hidden.

```
<div id="results" style="display: none"> ... </div>
```

Comment: +1, but I would make the `#results` style hidden by default so it starts that way automatically and is then un-hidden by the script.

Comment: Thank you Flimzy, But my results div is still visible even if I hide it the way you suggested.. My objective is to hide the results div till the spinner disappear (In this case, after 3 seconds)

Comment: @SathishPanduga: I've updated my answer to incorporate JohnU's suggestions, which may help you. If you're still having issues, you should update your question with all of your (relevant) HTML and CSS as well. But it looks like you've accepted an answer, so I'm guessing you figured it out.